# What in the world is "neckbeard vomit"?

Tags: expressions, terminology, slang

A user of [U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) posted the [following comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81829/delete-lines-in-a-csv-file-older-than-7-days/81830#comment120911_81830) in response to somebody's answer:

> That's some neckbeard vomit right there. Nice.

I [investigated](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=neckbeard) and discovered that *neckbeard*, unsurprisingly, means

> Facial hair that does not exist on the face, but instead on the neck. Almost never well groomed.

OK, but what is neckbeard *vomit*? Google only returns [four hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22neckbeard%20vomit%22) for the phrase and one of them is the comment in question. To make matters worse, the poster of the comment seems to consider it a compliment, while to me it seems very much the opposite.

So, what is *neckbeard vomit*? Is this a geek slang term I have not come across or was it coined by the comment's author?

Comment: I would think that _vomit_ refers to the content of the user's post (_i.e._, it's dreck) and that _neckbeard_ disparagingly refers to the user. Is it possible that the "Nice" cited in that comment is sarcastic? I'm at work and can't click your link but those are my impressions.

Comment: @longstreth that was my initial impression but no, it seems to be complimentary. It appeared along with an upvote and the author responded to my query by saying "
"we should all aspire to that level". It sounds like they were using it as a compliment.

Comment: See http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3173/whats-the-non-literal-meaning-of-neckbeard

Comment: @choster thanks but it was the positive meaning of vomit derived from the positive meaning of sick that stumped me. I knew _sick_ could be good but _vomit_ I had not heard of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an "educated" guess based on my research...

It IS a compliment if you take the alternative meaning of "neckbeard" to refer to a programmer - one who's so focused that they work for a couple days straight without shaving - thus growing a visible amount of "neckbeard".  (I got this connotation from a smattering of sites when I Google'd "neckbeard".  There wasn't anything official - just comments on Q/A sites).

and then combine that with definition of "vomit" from the Urban Dictionary:

> 1. vomit
>
> Vomit-Superlative, or outrageous. More than sick. (Sick is a compliment too)
>
> *"That big wave was so sick it was vomit."*

So "neckbeard vomit" could be the very excellent work of a dedicated coder.

Comment: Ah, I had never heard of vomit being used in a positive context, thanks, +1.

Comment: @terdon, alas, me neither! (feeling old today!) lol!

Comment: Good grief. (That expression alone probably dates me; Charlie Brown, anyone? I am becoming my father.) +1 anyway.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, at least now you have a cutting-edge expression to add to your vocabulary!  Lol!

Comment: @KristinaLopez one might even call it a _chucking_-edge expression (apologies, I couldn't resist).

Answer (score 2):

The user in question gave his own explanation which is close but not quite identical to @KristinaLopez's suggestion:

> @terdon - The accepted answer on english.stackexchange.com is pretty much right. A neckbeard (at least in the context used by my peers) is an older, wiser UNIX guru (usually someone who started using UNIX back in the sixties or seventies) and the context for "vomit" in this case refers to the unreadability, but succinctness of the answer.